# What is this 6 pin SMD? CASD or CAS0 is written on it

Tags: surface-mount

What is this 6 pin SMD? CASD or CAS0 is written on it. Can't seem to find its datasheet.

[image]

This is a water monitor, and I can't seem to find the datasheet for this part. Can anybody help me?

I first thought it was an octocoupler, but was proven wrong.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to EE! Could you add a picture with more of the surroundings? It helps to see the other circuitry in order to identify the component. What does it monitor by the way?